# passing variable to directive via scope angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a variable which i want to pass to my directive via scope and then use that variable in link if it is possible. I am fairly new using directives a few things are a bit blurr to me. This is my current code

```
    .directive('imagesFormat', function($cordovaCamera, $ionicModal, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          datasource: '&',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("click", function() {
           if(attrs.imagesFormat === "takePhoto") {
              var options = {
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                correctOrientation: true
              };
            }
           if(attrs.imagesFormat === "choosePhoto") {
              var options = {
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                correctOrientation: true
              };
            }
          scope.activeSlide = scope.datasource;
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

my html code

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll='false'>
      <div class= "row">
      <div class="col">
        <button images-format="takePhoto" datasource="$index">Take Photo</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button images-format="choosePhoto" datasource="$index">Image Gallery/File</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

So basically what i want to be able to get in my directive is the value of `$index` and assign it to `scope.activeSlide = scope.datasource` thats all

Comment: datasource: '&', & is used for function for varible use "="

Comment: Where is $index coming from? is it a custom function, variable or string you are setting on your scope? or is it from an angular directive such as ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

By adding **scope** to the directive we create an "*isolated scope*". With this approach **scope** can capture attributes in 3 ways:

1. **`@`** Captures the attribute value from the DOM as string value.
2. **`=`** Evaluates the attribute as property of the parent scope.
3. **`&`** Evaluates the attribute as method of the parent scope.

You can read more about it here:

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

Based on your example above it seems that you need to change your `&` with an  `=`

```
restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          datasource: '=',
        },
```

Comment: `datasource: '=$index',` this is wrong. This would imply that datasource is expected to be set from a DOM attribute called $index, e.g. `<button data-images-format="choosePhoto" data-$index="...">`

Comment: This is by far the cleanest way I've seen of the @,=,& breakdown of directives.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope: {
    datasource: '&',
}
```

By doing this you are stating that you expect datasource to be bound to, effectively, a function pointer. If this is what you require then that is fine.
However if you want to bind to a variable/expression use `'='`, or if you want to bind to a string use `'@'`.

Some other points as well.

You only seem to then use `datasource` to set a new scope variable (new since you are now working with an isolated scope):

`scope.activeSlide = scope.datasource;`

This from the look of it is redundant. You can simply reference `scope.datasource` wherever you need it instead rather then basically creating what is a duplicate at this stage.

Secondly you are accessing `imagesFormat` through the use of the `attrs` provider, which is fine... but note that you could also have this defined on the scope:

```
scope: {
    datasource: '&',
    imagesFormat: '@'
}
```

and then use:

```
<button images-format="takePhoto" datasource="$index">Take Photo</button>
```

and

```
if(scope.imagesFormat === "takePhoto")
```